# Good resources for learning Data Access Object through Hibernate framework

Tags: java, hibernate, dao

Please list some good resources, wherein I can learn Data Access Objects in Java and their use in great detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visit http://techtracer.com/2008/12/30/the-great-hibernate-tutorial-a-great-jump-start-for-beginners/ for basic understanding.

Once, you understood the basics, Google is always there to move ahead (Read official documentations for DAO and Hibernate)! :)